# Pattern to keep track of Collection of Objects passed to External Web Service?

Tags: c#, algorithm, web-services, design-patterns

I am having difficulty in coming up with the best Design or pattern for a solution I am trying to implement in C#.

Problem -

My application is going to be calling an external WebService asynchronously to retrieve responses.  The external web-service can only take 5000 Addresses per request.  However I would like my approach to be if my User uploads 3000 address I would like to split them into batches of 1000 and pass to the External WebService and get response but if there were 15,000 uploaded by User I would want to split them into packages of 5000 and pass to external webservice.

The pseudo type code for the methods on the External Web Service I would be calling is as:

```
tokenId = GetInfoForAddress(Addresses[] addresses)

progStatus = GetProgStatus(tokenId);

if (progrStatus == "Complete")
{
addressResponse = GetResults(tokenId); 
}
else
{

 //handle other statuses
}
```

So basically webservice returns a token id for a number of address I pass in and then I can get the status of the service based on the token id and then if status is complete I can get the results.

However I am unsure of what the best way to handle the case were I need to first take a count of addresses and then say if less than 5000 split into packages of 1000 and if more than 5000 split into packages of 5000 would look like.  I am thing I would need to generate a unique GUID before splitting so that I can package up the results to the original 3000 or 15000 for e.g when the results come back.

Has anyone done anything similar to this and can perhaps provide a simple pseudo code or sequence diagram of the process/pattern used?

Answer (score 1):

The 'best' pattern is to keep all this plumbing internal and get an unique call method and behavior exposed as API whenever you send 1000 or 10000 addresses.

This is common into messaging app such AMQP or JMS.

Following code i wrote for an embeded AMQP brocker where the transfert could be splitted into chunck depending the size accepted by the client/brocker.
The entire request is stored into unsettled map (using unique key ) and remain unsettled until all the part has been processed successfully.

Hope this will help.

```
    private async Task<uint> InternalTransfertAsyncWithGaranty(IAMQPEnvelope p_envelope, CancellationToken p_token)
    {
        // ask session the delivery id
        uint l_deliveryId = Session.MessageIdentificationProvider.NewIdentifier(this.Handle);

        // add to unsettled map
        _unsettled.Add(l_deliveryId, p_envelope);

        try
        {
            // transfert
            await InternalSplitTransfertAsync(p_envelope.Key, l_deliveryId, p_envelope.Payload, true, p_token);
        }
        catch
        {
            // if something goes wrong, such cancellation or I/O
            IAMQPEnvelope l_env;
            if (_unsettled.Remove(l_deliveryId, out l_env))
            {
            }
            // lets Exception exit
            throw;
        }

        return l_deliveryId;
    }

    private async Task InternalSplitTransfertAsync(string p_deliveryTag, uint p_deliveryId, ArraySegment<byte> p_payload, bool p_settled, CancellationToken p_token)
    {
        IAMQPConnection l_conn = Session.Connection as IAMQPConnection;
        uint l_blockSize = l_conn.Capabilities.MaxFrameSize;
        int l_initialsize = p_payload.Count;
        if (l_initialsize < l_blockSize)
        {
            // just send one transfert
            await InternalSingleTransfertAsync(p_deliveryTag, p_deliveryId, false, p_payload, p_settled, p_token);
        }
        else
        {
            // cut transfert onto pieces. Message MUST NOT be interleaved. The order of delivery lets message beeing reconstrucetd.
            int l_offset = p_payload.Offset;
            int l_count = (int)l_blockSize;
            int l_remain = l_initialsize;
            bool l_more = true;
            int l_size = 0;
            do
            {
                l_size = l_remain <= l_count ? l_remain : l_count;
                l_more = l_offset + l_size < l_initialsize;
                await InternalSingleTransfertAsync(null, p_deliveryId, l_more, new ArraySegment<byte>(p_payload.Array, l_offset, l_size), p_settled, p_token);
                l_offset += l_size;
                l_remain -= l_size;
            } while (l_more);
        }
    }

    private async Task InternalSingleTransfertAsync(string p_deliveryTag, uint p_deliveryId, bool p_more, ArraySegment<byte> p_payload, bool p_settled, CancellationToken p_token)
    {
        AMQPTransfert l_transfert = InternalBuildTransfert(p_deliveryTag, p_settled, p_deliveryId, p_more);
        AMQPFrame l_frame = InternalBuildFrame(l_transfert, p_payload);
        await Session.SendAsync(l_frame, p_token);
    }
```

Comment: I have to say, I've never seen such prefixing before. What is it's purpose? I assume "p" is for parameters and "l" is for "local" variables? It is very distracting to me. Wouldn't it be better to keep it "standard" on answers here?.

Comment: you're right, comming from very old "hungarian" style was used in java during the mid 90's.

Answer (score 0):

## Assumptions

- You have an array of addresses.
- You have a process that stays running (i.e. Controller) that initiates the request(s) (i.e. Requester).

### Requester

I think in the requester I'd have a method like this:

```
public List<string> GetResponses(params string[] addresses)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    var skipCount = 0;
    var takeCount = addresses.Length < 5000 ? 1000 : 5000;

    string[] request;
    while ((request = addresses.Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount).ToArray()).Length > 0)
    {
        skipCount += takeCount;
        result.Add(service.Request(request));
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Controller

In the controller, I think I'd use a `BackgroundWorker` to check the status of the responses. So maybe in the `ctor` of the controller I'd initialize a `private` field:

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

public Controller()
{
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
    _worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void ControllerMethod()
{
    var tokens = requester.GetResponses(addresses);
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync(tokens);
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var tokens = e.Argument as List<string>;
    if (tokens == null) { return; }

    // declare the result variable here
    // I don't know what it is; but you'll concatenate
    // the results below where I show the response

    var completedTokens = new List<string>();
    while (completedTokens.Count < tokens.Count)
    {
        foreach (var tokenId in tokens)
        {
            var status = GetProgStatus(tokenId);
            if (status == "Complete")
            {
                completedTokens.Add(tokenId);

                // maybe call
                // worker.ReportProgress(completedTokens.Count, "some status text");

                var response = GetResults(tokenId);

                // if response is a list or array, just use LINQ to
                // add the response to an overall result that is declared
                // outside of the while loop
            }
            else
            {
                // check other statuses here and maybe call
                // worker.ReportProgress(completedTokens.Count, "some status text");
            }
        }

        // sleep for some duration and check again
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    e.Result = result;
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // here you can use that real percentage complete value to set
    // a progress bar; or maybe SignalR to send a progress if you're
    // inside a web application

    // this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    // and now here you can even grab that textual progress
    var progress = e.UserState as string;
}

private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // here you can now get at that result
    var result = e.Result as {SomeType};
}
```

By sending in `completedTokens.Count` to `ReportProgress` you're getting a real progress. If there were 3 tokens returned and 1 is complete then you are truly 33% complete.

Comment: If my methods are async do I need to create the Background worker thread?  If I have a method that say splits the Array of addresses into n Batches couldn't I kick off n tasks in Parrallel to GetTicketID, GetProgress of each and then Finally GetResults

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

```
public class GetInfoForAddressAggregate
{
    private AddressBatch[] _batches;

    public GetInfoForAddressAggregate(Address[] addresses)
    {
        if (addresses.Length >= 5000)
        {
            _batches = SplitIntoBatches(addresses, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
            _batches = SplitIntoBatches(addresses, 1000);
        }
    }

    private AddressBatch[] SplitIntoBatches(Address[] addresses, int size)
    {
        // stubbed method
        return null;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        foreach (var batch in _batches)
        {
            batch.Run();
        }
    }

    public bool IsComplete
    {
        get { return _batches.All(x => x.IsComplete); }
    }



    private class AddressBatch
    {
        private Address[] _addresses;
        private string _token;

        public string Token
        {
            get { return _token; }
        }

        public AddressBatch(Address[] addresses)
        {
            _addresses = addresses;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            _token = GetInfoForAddress(_addresses);
        }

        private string GetProgStatus(string token)
        {
            // stubbed method
            return "Complete";
        }

        private string GetInfoForAddress(Address[] addresses)
        {
            // stubbed method
            return "token";
        }

        public bool IsComplete
        {
            get { return _token != null && GetProgStatus(_token) == "Complete"; }
        }

    }
```

I think your goal here is to simplify and hide the details of the batch splitting, and that's what this aggregate does.  The caller doesn't have to be aware of the batch splitting rules and can use it as if it weren't needed.